# << was unexpected at this time. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i work on a flutter project but after uploading the file to github and trying to debug the code the terminal this response

```
<< was unexpected at this time.
```

i have fork repositorie of flutter maybe this cause the prob

i try to remove the flutter fork in my github but nothing happen
i check the FlutterGitUrl in the envirement variable but it was

> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

i try `flutter doctor` but same line appear
the only command working is `dart`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to delete the Flutter SDK folder then re-download again.

This happens when there are conflicts inside the Flutter SDK local repository (Flutter uses Git to manage itself).

I am not sure why it happens though. But since the SDK become unusable, it's far easier to just download a fresh SDK (same version) and delete the old one than searching for and solving conflicts throughout the SDK codebase.

- Link to download a specific version of Flutter: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this error by simply resetting the flutter SDK folder from git command:

1. Go to folder flutter SDK folder eg: C:\flutter\
2. Run this command: `git reset --hard</c>`
3. Run "flutter doctor" to check for any other errors

This will restore the flutter SDK folder to its original state. No need to reinstall the complete SDK.